# Breezejs EntityType.createEntity is not wrapping properties with observables

Tags: javascript, breeze

breeze is supposed to wrap properties with observable and observableArrays by default, right? Why is it not doing it in this case?

```
var apiService = new breeze.DataService({
    serviceName: 'api',
    hasServerMetadata: false
});

var store = new breeze.MetadataStore({
    namingConvention: breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase
});

var movieType = new breeze.EntityType({
    shortName: 'Movie',
    dataProperties: [
        new breeze.DataProperty({
            name: "id",
            dataType: breeze.DataType.ID,
            isNullable: false,
            isPartOfKey: true
        }),
        new breeze.DataProperty({
            name: "title",
            dataType: breeze.DataType.String,
            isNullable: false
        })
    ]
});

store.addEntityType(movieType);

function Movie() {
    var self = this;

    self.isBeingEdited = false;
}

store.registerEntityTypeCtor('Movie', Movie);

var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
    dataService: apiService,
    metadataStore: store
});

var favoriteMovie = movieType.createEntity({
    id: 123,
    title: "5th Element",
    stars: ['Bruce Willis', 'Milla Yovovich']
});

manager.addEntity(favoriteMovie);

alert(favoriteMovie.title()); //errors favoriteMovie.title is not a function
```

Answer (score 2):

The above code is fine. The problem was that I included `breeze.js` before `knockout.js` The order of inclusion is important.